# Dockbar in kubuntu 12.04 64

Tags: kubuntu, kde

im looking for some dockbar like avant-window-navigator in Gnome.

I tried Daisy but isnt found in repositories list...I also tried installing the plasma-widget-icon-tasks. I added gnumdk/ppa repository to install it, but not found.

Comment: The Daisy (0.0.4.25) was dropped from the official Ubuntu repositories: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-widget-daisy/+bug/910902 . The Daisy from a PPA: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=102077 -> http://cdlszm.org/pages/download.php . The icontasks is part of the KDE (4.8 and later) release - package name is plasma-widgets-addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Cairo-dock before in Ubuntu, according to a quick [google search](http://linux4noobs.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/dockbarforlinux/), it works in KDE as well. While not as feature rich, it is cross platform. Here is the [launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/cairo-dock) for the Cairo-Dock project, which even includes instructions for how to install the software on several different distributions of linux. For example, in Ubuntu:

```
echo "deb http://download.tuxfamily.org/glxdock/repository/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) cairo-dock" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list 
wget -q http://download.tuxfamily.org/glxdock/repository/cairo-dock.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

Comment: cairo doesnt need compiz?

Comment: According to the launchpad site, it can use Compiz, but will also use other Window Managers, like Kwin.

Comment: oh perfect, i had not used cairo thinking need compiz. thanks hank!